# Updating / exporting to an excel file from R without saving a new workbook (corrupting graphs and other objects)

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I want to write data from R into an existing excel file which has predefined graphs with specific formatting and multiple sheets.

I have tried to do this in a number of ways. The most promising was the openxlsx package (Seen below). The problem with this solution was that when using the `loadWorkbook()` function it seems to fail to load all workbook features such as complex graph formatting, pictures and smartArt. This results in a corrupted excel workbook when saving.

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file = "template.xlsx")                  
writeData(wb = wb,sheet = 1, startCol = sCol, startRow = sRow,x = genData)
saveWorkbook(wb, "populatedTemplate.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

It would be great if I could directly write data into a specific sheet of an existing excel workbook without having to load the whole workbook into memory and then recreate it afterwards. The `xlsx::write.xlsx()` function does this, however, it is only possible to append a sheet to a current excel file and not write to a specific sheet without overwriting the whole file.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Any luck at all on this?  I'm having the same problem can't believe this hasn't been addressed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember my final workaround. I have since moved on from `R`